# Hide/Unhide Rows in Excel in VSTO application C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

My Task is to Hide/Unhide rows of an excel workbook on the basis of whether a string exists in a particular row or not. The problem I am facing is that it is taking me about 20 seconds to perform this task on 1000 Rows with the following code. The file might be having as many as 2k-3k rows and I want to reduce this  loading time.

It is to be noted that when I comment the line in my code that "hides/unhides" the entire row(currentFind.EntireRow.Hidden = !isShown;), then excel file takes only 4-5 seconds to load. This makes me conclude that it is the row hiding part which is time consuming and not the searching of string part.

```
        Worksheet activeWorksheet= Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;
        Range usedRange = activeWorksheet.UsedRange;

        Range currentFind = null;
        Range firstFind = null;

        currentFind = activeWorksheet.UsedRange.Find(searchInput);

        while (currentFind != null)
        {
            // Keep track of the first range you find. 
            if (firstFind == null)
            {
                firstFind = currentFind;
            }

            // If you didn't move to a new range, you are done.
            else if (currentFind.get_Address(XlReferenceStyle.xlA1)
                  == firstFind.get_Address(XlReferenceStyle.xlA1))
            {
                break;
            }

            currentFind.EntireRow.Hidden = !isShown;

            currentFind = usedRange.FindNext(currentFind);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Globals.ThisAddin.Application.ScreeenUpdating = false at the beginning
and set it to true at the end.
Also You might throw Globals.ThisAddin.Application.EnableEvents = false at start
and true at the end.

Comment: Did the solution work for you? If so mark it as an answer please

Answer (score 0):

I've found that doing anything to a row (or range or cell) at a time when it's the same thing seems to always take longer than doing it over the entire range in one fell swoop.  For example, I once wrote something that deleted all rows that were completely blank, and it ran in the blink of an eye when I did it as one statement (`Range.Delete`) versus over a loop, which took quite a while.

In that spirit, what if you revisited your code and gathered all rows that contain the string in question and then hid them all at once:

```
Excel.Range hideRange = null;
Excel.Application xl = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

foreach (Excel.Range row in activeWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows)
{
    if (oApp.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(row, "*" + searchInput + "*") > 0)
        hideRange = hideRange == null ? row : xl.Union(hideRange, row);
}

hideRange.EntireRow.Hidden = true;
```

I can't promise this code is faster, but try it and let us know how it compares.  I am pretty confident the last line will run fast; what remains to be seen is how the loop that identifies the occurrences runs.

I tested it on some fake data, and for thousands of rows with hundreds of rows to be hidden, the "hide" line of code only took 156 ms, or 0.15 seconds.